# Custom font in Extending TextView? Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've got a lot of problems with 'normal' custom fonts in my fragment so i decided to make everything from this tutorial:

https://futurestud.io/tutorials/custom-fonts-on-android-extending-textview

And it doesn't works. I'm not getting any error. Please help me!

Comment: it's because it's catching the error for you. Where it says catch in FontCache.java, replace returns null with Log.e("failed", e.getMessage()); and then post your error.

Answer (score 1):

**You can use** 
Smart Fonts for Android is a Library which makes it easy to use Custom Fonts in Apps
https://github.com/smart-fun/SmartFonts

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class LoveTextView extends TextView {
        private static final String TAG = "TextView";

        public LoveTextView(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        public LoveTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
            setCustomFont(context, attrs);
        }

        public LoveTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);
            setCustomFont(context, attrs);
        }

        private void setCustomFont(Context ctx, AttributeSet attrs) {
            TypedArray a = ctx.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.LoveTextView);
            String customFont = a.getString(R.styleable.LoveTextView_customFont);
            setCustomFont(ctx, customFont);
            a.recycle();
        }

        public boolean setCustomFont(Context ctx, String asset) {
            Typeface tf = null;
            try {
                tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(ctx.getAssets(), asset);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Could not get typeface: " + e.getMessage());
                return false;
            }

            setTypeface(tf);
            return true;
        }

    }




than you can use textview class in xml file . like below

 <com.love.ui.LoveTextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left|center"
            android:text="@string/add_product"
            android:textColor="@color/title_text_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/material_medium_one"
            app:customFont="fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf" />
```